# C, Way to make multiply in array element fast

Tags: c, numpy, optimization

```
import numpy as np
array = np.random.rand(16384)
array *= 3
```

above python code make each element in array has 3 times multiplied value of its own.
On my Laptop, these code took 5ms

Below code is what i tried on C language.

```
#include <headers...>

array = make 16384 elements...;


for(int i = 0 ; i < 16384 ; ++i)
    array[i] *= 3
```

compile command was

```
gcc -O2 main.cpp
```

it takes almost 30ms.
Is there any way i can reduce process time of this?

P.S it was my fault. I confused unit of timestamp value.
this code is faster than numpy. sorry for this question.

Comment: What language?  C or C++?  Please post a [mcve] of the program you are claiming is slow, plus post compiler, compiler options used, etc. that you used to build the test program.  We need to ensure that you are compiling 1) a correct program, and 2) Building an *optimized* version of the program, and not testing an unoptimized "debug" build.

Comment: That cannot be the C code you used; it will not compile. Without knowing how you measured the time and on what processor with what clock speed, the 30 ms report is useless. If your measurement includes the time to start and stop the program, it is not measuring the time to multiply the elements of the array, which would be a small fraction of that time; it is measuring system overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds pretty unbelievable. For reference, I wrote a trivial (but complete) program that does roughly what you seem to be describing. I used C++ so I could use its chrono library to get (much) more precise timing than C's `clock` provides, but I wouldn't expect that to affect the speed at all.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

#define SIZE (16384)

float array[SIZE];

int main() {
    using namespace std::chrono;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        array[i] = i;
    }

    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
        array[i] *= 3.0;
    }
    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout << duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start).count() << '\n';

    long total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        total += i;
    }
    std::cout << "Ignore: " << total << "\n";
}
```

On my machine (2.8 GHz Haswell, so probably slower than whatever you're running) this shows a time of 7 or 8 **microseconds**, so around 600-700 times as fast as you're getting from Python.

Adding the compiler flag to use AVX 2 instructions reduces that to 4 microseconds, or a little more than 1000 times as fast (warning: AMD processors generally don't get as much of a speed boost from using AVX 2, but if you have a reasonably new AMD processor I'd expect it to be faster than this anyway).

Bottom line: the speed you're reporting for your C code only seems to make sense if you're running the code on some sort of slow microcontroller, or maybe a really old desktop system--though it would have to be *quite* old to run nearly as slow as you're reporting. My immediate guess is that even a 386 would be faster than that.

When/if you have something that takes enough time to justify it, you can also use OpenMP to run a loop like this in multiple threads. I tried that, but in this case the overhead of starting up and synchronizing the threads is (quite a bit) more than running in parallel can gain, so it's a net loss.

Compiler: VS 2019 (Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.27.28919.3 for x64).
Flags: /O2b2 /GL (and part of the time, /arch:AVX2)

Comment: AVX2 on a Sandybridge?

Comment: @Shawn: oops. I should have checked--my memory isn't the best any more.